# Exam Question - language recognizition

Tags: finite-automata

I was at the Math-exam yesterday, and I am a bit unsure, if i solved a math problem correctly.

The question was something like this:

> Draw a automata that recognise the following language:
>   $$ L = \{w : (0 | 1)^* \text{and } w \text{ ends with } 00 \} $$

See the image below where $q_3$ is the accept-state.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, please try and explain a little better

Comment: Look at the image i posted. Does it recognise the language i posted?

Comment: I am not able to answer this question because I understand little about automata, but some of your notation, such as the asterisk, may not be accessible to someone who does understand. What is W? a string of 1s and 0s? what is w, a variable?

Comment: Yes, w is a string of 1s and 0s. Yes w is a variable.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect what you mean. Is there a difference between big W and little w?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, W should be little w.

Comment: You're missing a transition from q3 to q1 on a 1.  As drawn, your automaton rejects 00100 (assuming no transition means reject).

Comment: That automaton accepts $L = \{ (0|1)^*00(0|1)^* \}$. To fix and for sake of clarity you might add the transitions $\delta(q_3, 0) = q_3$  and $\delta(q_3, 1) = q_1$ to get a nice DFA.

Answer (score 1):

Your automaton should not accept the string $1001$. It needs transitions $(q_3,0)\rightarrow q_3$ and $(q_3,1) \rightarrow q_1$.